# My second splash screen wont open and i am getting no errors

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am having trouble with this splash screen. The first one should last 3 seconds then go to the second splash, but all that is happening is the first opens up then nothing else happens any ideas?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash1 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash1);
}

final Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {

    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Intent splash2 = new Intent("com.zombieface.dubsnake.SPLASH2");
            startActivity(splash2);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

This is the Manifest:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".Splash1"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:label="Dub Snake"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Splash2"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:label="Dub Snake"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.zombieface.dubsnake.SPLASH2" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is all your code then you forgot to actually start the thread `logoTimer` so you never get in that loop and start the new activity.
From your `onCreate()` call:

```
 logoTimer.start();
```